# index is repeated when switching between prev/next pagination

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to display 15 posts each time I click on next or prev. Currently, when I click on next and I'm on for example at `index` of value 5, when I click on prev, it shows `index` at value 5 again then it decrements to 4 and so on.

How do I make it not repeat while switching between prev and next? 
This is a simplified example:

```
var array = [0,1,2,3, ...,50]
    var index = 0
    var button = 
 document.querySelectorAll("button").addEventListener("click",paginate)   

   paginate(e) {
            var target = e.currentTarget.dataset.button,
                postsPerPage = 15,
                posts = array.length,
                total = Math.ceil(posts / postsPerPage),
                index = target === 'next' ? index++ : --index,
                //... 
        }
```

Comment: So is it 10 or 15?

Comment: 15. Ive just updated my post.

Comment: So what doesn't work?

Comment: You haven't explained the problem you're facing. We have no idea what the issue might be.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to implement displaying next or previous posts on click.

Comment: Ok so edit your question with a lot more detail, e.g. "The problem I'm facing is... when I click on Next, what happens is... but what I want to happen is... I have tried x, but that causes ... to happen which is not the desired behavior"

Comment: What's the for loop for? What's the expected value of this.posts.length? What is `this` supposed to be? Because it looks to me like that is going to me like that `this` isn't going to do you much good. Did you console.log every value after setting it? I'm sure you'll find out where it's going wrong if you do.

Comment: The for loop? It's just for creating an array for demonstration. the `this` is a prop from a class which i've forgotten to take off. it works good on my end. it just bad formatting. I've fixed the issue.

Comment: But still hasnt solved the repeating index increment/decrement on click

Answer (score 0):

As much as I've suspected, the issue was from `index++` and `--index` I've replaced them, respectively, with `index= index+1` and `index = index -1`, and it worked. If someone could explain why the index repeat itself, it would be highly appreciated.

```
   paginate(e) {
            var target = e.currentTarget.dataset.button,
                postsPerPage = 15,
                posts = array.length,
                total = Math.ceil(posts / postsPerPage),
                index = target === 'next' ? index=index +1:index=index-1,
                //...

        }
```